# PHPMailer doesn't send embed image

Tags: php, phpmailer

I have to add a signature to an email using phpmailer but all my attemp failed and i tried many solutions given here or on other forum but the image doesn't appear in the end when i receive the mail.

This is the basic code i use to test it:

```
$mail->IsHTML(true);
$mail->AddEmbeddedImage('test.JPG', "logoimg", "test.JPG"); // attach file logo.jpg, and later link to it using identfier logoimg
$mail->Body = "
      <h1>Test 1 of PHPMailer html</h1>
      <p><img src=\"cid:logoimg\" />This is a test picture: </p>";
$mail->AddAddress($email, '');
$mail->Send();
```

I also tried putting it in base64 but the result is a block of characters and not an image.

So if you have any idea or recomendation, please tell me ^^
Thank you for your help

Update :
If I test the return of $mail->AddEmbeddedImage like Synchro told me it goes in the false section.

```
if($mail->AddEmbeddedImage('test.JPG', "my-attach", "test.JPG", 'base64', 'image/jpeg')){
     $mail->Body = 'Embedded Image: <img alt="PHPMailer" src="cid:my-attach">';
 }else{
     $mail->Body = 'No Embedded Image';
 }
```

Comment: Are you sure the image is being accessed/read correctly by your PHP script? Check that the path is correct. In this case, the image is expected to be in the same directory where this logic is invoked, which might not be the case.

Comment: i did it on purpose to only worry about the code, my file test.JPG is in the same file as the php file :)

Comment: Check the return status of `addEmbeddedImage`; that will tell you if it's reading the file correctly.

Comment: Oh it looks like it is not reading it correctly, could you tell me where the problem could be comming from?